# Using pymssql to connect to sql server in Ubuntu

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to use pymssql library to connect to the sql server in ubuntu but got the following error. But I tried the same script in the mac and it works.

I think there is a FreeTDS configuration problem in ubuntu but almost tried all of the recommanded methods in the web still no luck so far. Anyone can point me to the right direction?

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='blah.database.windows.net', 
                       user='blah', 
                       password='!', 
                       database='database')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table')

data = cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    database='my data base')
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n')
```

Comment: Some internet comments on the error point to a TLS lib problem. One guy stated that manual compiling pymssql helped for him.

Comment: that won't work. tried that already